# Rails send individual email to each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise, actionmailer

I'm sending around 100 emails at a time using the following mailer in my Rails 3 application:

```
def new_resource_notification(resource, user)
  @resource = resource
  @user = user
  mails = User.where(:email_subscribe => true).map(&:email)
  mail(:to => "admin@domain.com", :bcc => mails, :subject => "New item added")
end
```

When I look at the outgoing email logs it's sending each email to `admin@domain.com` and adding all users to the bcc field as expected.

What I would prefer, if possible, is for each email to be sent to the users email without any bcc entries.

Is this possible and/or recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you will have to do a loop, which will send single e-mail to each user. It will take much more rescources and will be slower; that's why lots of mailers do "BCC method" rather than send single emails.

Comment: I've just realised it's sending an email to every user but includes every user in the BCC field. That means each user will receive this email once X the number of users. In other words, it's sending the email to every user 100 times..

Comment: I don't know how your `new_resource_notification()` is called, but if it sends 100 e-mails to a single user it it either means that the loop is created somewhere else or you have 100 alike addresses in your rescource?